# Is aged beef salted and soaked before or after the aging process?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, meat, salt

Some kosher butchers are now offering aged beef.  Is this meat [salted and soaked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shechita#Kashering) before or after the aging process?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Victor I Beck, and thanks for the interesting question. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including our sixty-one other [tag:meat]-related questions. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

Before, presumably. A law was instituted by the Gaonim that if you're planning on salting meat to extract the blood (rather than broiling it), it must be soaked or at least hosed down within the first 72 hours after slaughter -- and then every 72 hours after that.

Comment: Not everyone agrees to the splashing every 72 hours,see Taz ,Schach and I think the Gilyon Maharsha

Comment: Not that familiar with the rules of kashering (yet) .... do you mean "broiling" or "roasting"?

Answer (score 3):

Since one has 72 hours(Geonim) from shechita to do nikkur and melicha I would assume that it was done first because aging takes more than 3 days.